# How can I place form fields inline with text?

Tags: css, html, layout, styles

[image: Website screenshot]

I'm trying to put the mailing list button on the right side of the address. I am just starting out and this has frustrated me for many days. I have been learning using the W3 school but can't quite work out how to move it. At first I was using divs but then learned more about the span element. I thought that would fix it but alas, I need help.

Just to make sure I understood, I am trying to have the mailing list button and input to the right hand of the "Visit our warehouse" text rather than have it below.

```html
<span>
Visit our wholesale warehouse<br>
7507 Kingspointe Parkway<br>
Suite 101<br>
Orlando, FL. 32819<br>
US<br>
Phone: 407-420-<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?oi=map&q=7507%20Kingspointe%20Parkway+Orlando+FL+32819">Directions</a>
</span>
  <!--START: FRAME_MAILLIST-->
<span class='container'>
  <span class='fieldName'>
    <form method="post" name="mailing" action="mailing_list.asp?action=add" onsubmit=" mailing_list();">
      <label style="font—size:160%;">[frame_mailinglist]</label></span>
      <span class="mailist-box">
      </span>
      <span class='data'>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input type="submit" name="www" value="[mailinglist_button]" />
        <input class="clear"></span>
      </span >
      <input type="radio" name="subscribe" value="1" checked="checked" />
      <span class="menu-text">[mailinglist_subscribe]</span>
      <input type="radio" name="subscribe" value="0" />
      <span class="menu-text">[mailinglist_unsubscribe]</span>
      <span class="clear"></span>
    </form>
  </span>
  </span>
    </span>
<span class="clear"></span>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). *Images of code etc are **not** an acceptable substitute*.

Comment: Welcome, Will. Unfortunately, we don't do well with screenshots. Post the code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use `div` elements here. But what you are really looking for is a CSS property called `flexbox`.

First, here's how I would structure your HTML:

```
<div class="overall-container">
  <div class="address-container">
   /* address html goes here /*
  </div>
  <div class="mailing-list-container">
   /* mailing list html goes here /*
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, in your CSS you can write the following:

```
.overall-container {
  width: 100vw; // You can adjust the width of the whole container here

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; // This is the most important part for you
  justify-content: center; // Look up other options if this doesn't fit
  align-items: center; // Again look up for other options
}
```

This will put your address container `div` and your mailing-list container `div` side by side with each other. The `flex-direction` property of `row` controls this. If you wanted them on top of each other, then set `flex-direction: column`.

Hope this helps. If you need more information, look up CSS flexbox on MDN.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for, flexbox it is! thanks again!

Comment: @WillSimpson No problem man. Good luck on your journey learning web development